# JSON PUT Request Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use to a PUT call to a API using JSON. I am using jQuery and from what I can tell my code looks right:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://app.clickdimensions.com/Service.svc/v1/account/accountIdHere/capture',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: { 'reg_FirstName': 'First',
                    'reg_LastName': 'Last',
                    'reg_Phone': '123-342-1211',
                    'reg_Email': 'email@email.com',
                    'reg_Company': 'My Company',
                    'reg_Address1': '123 Traffic Lane',
                    'reg_Address2': '',
                    'reg_City': 'Atlanta',
                    'reg_State': 'GA',
                    'reg_Zip': '12232',
                    'reg_Country': 'United States'  
            },
            success: function() { alert('PUT completed'); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app.clickdimensions.com/Service.svc/v1/account/accountIdHere/capture. Origin http://localhost:65116 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've looked everywhere and tried about everything I can find to no avail. So I'm thinking my code might be wrong to do a JSON PUT call. Does my code look wrong? If so how could I fix it. If not, any idea on that error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, however it is not possible to do a PUT request cross-domain unless the domain you are requesting data from is returning the proper [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers.

Comment: Thanks, that actually explains a lot. There wouldn't happen to be any type of work around would there? It's one of those cases I probably won't get much help from the guys on the server side.

Comment: The only workaround is to use a proxy on your server that makes the request for you. Your javascript would request the data from your server, and your server would request the data from the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery looks good. The problem lies in `Origin http://localhost:65116 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

This suggests [Cross-Domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) resource loading, which is verboten in most situations. If you have control over `https://app.clickdimensions.com/Service.svc/v1/account/accountIdHere/capture` you can modify it to allow such requests from specific domains, or you could use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of JSON to do cross-domain requests, although I'm unsure of your success with an HTTP PUT in such an instance. JSONP, to my knowledge, needs to be an HTTP GET.